# Closed form of to calculate variation of Pascal's triangle

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, stirling-numbers

So if you have Pascal's triangle, I know you can calculate any value in closed form.

```
   1
  1 1
 1 2 1
1 3 3 1
  ....
```

If we let `R` be the row number, then we can generate that triangle like this

```
         C(R,0)
      C(R,0) C(R,1) 
   C(R,0) C(R,1) C(R,2)
C(R,0) C(R,1) C(R,2) CR,3)
```

with the choose function `Choose(row#,column#)` but I have a variation on this that looks like this

```
                     C(R,0)*C(N,0)
              C(R,0)*C(N,0) C(R,1)*C(N,1) 
       C(R,0)*C(N,0) C(R,1)*C(N,1) C(R,2)*C(N,2)
C(R,0)*C(N,0) C(R,1)*C(N,1) C(R,2)*C(N,2) C(R,2)*C(N,3)
                         ....
```

So at point in Pascals triangle instead of `C(N,Column#)` you have `C(R,Column#)*C(N,Column#)`.  `Where R > Column#`.

So we can calculate any single value in closed form, but if I wanted to calculate a whole row or subset of a row, is there a closed form for that?

Comment: So you want a function that takes a row number and an interval $[a,b]$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{N}, a \leq b$ and returns a list of numbers?

Comment: A function that takes a row number `r` and an interval integer range `R` that is a subset of `[0,r-1]` and returns the sum of the terms of `R` from the variation of pascals triangle.

Comment: Okay. So it could be any subset of $[0, r-1]$ not just a sub-interval, right?

Comment: Actually, I had a subinterval in mind, but if you could do any subset then you could do a subinterval

Comment: How is your triangle built? How do you define `C(N,K)`?

Comment: I mean, i think it is defined.  You mean, what was i working on in order that I now have to come to need the sum of these coeficients?

Comment: Technically, I think $C(n,k)$ is considered not to be a closed form. You can use some form of Stirling's formula to approximate it if $n$ and $k$ are large, or you can compute it by some kind of iterative method, such as multiplying out the factorials or building part of Pascal's triangle. For the sum of a (partial) row of your triangle you can use a similarly iterative method. How big are values of $n$ and $r$ you need to work with?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no [known] closed-form formula to your problem (this link gives a bound to a similar problem: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n).

But we know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} = 2^n$, so if your interval is large, you can deduce the sum of the terms that you don't want to $2^n$ and compute the answer more quickly.

[Also, you can use the fact that the triangle is symmetric to speed up computation, by only considering one side and multiplying it by 2 (plus the middle term, if the row has an odd number of terms)]

Comment: I think you misunderstood, let me try to clarify

Comment: And I mean not that you misunderstood completely, but I could have done a better job of explaining